# What is the error, how to fix it Process finished with exit code -1073741795 (0xC0000010)

Tags: pycharm

I run the program in Pycharm without executing to the end, it ends with the code Process finished with exit code -1073741795 (0xC0000010), tell me how you can solve.
I Googled it roughly, I assume that there may be a lack of memory of 6GB RAM, but I'm not sure, since it works on another computer without any problems.

Comment: How can we help you if we have no idea on what you are doing? Note: "It work on other computer" is not a reason to think the code is correct. The error is about the stack size (so a specific part of memory). Possibly you are using some libraries (which you just do not want to tell us) or cython (the same). So try to upgrade or google with some more specific terms. Try with the debugger, and check where you have a crash.

Comment: The error occurs during photo recognition by the library easyocr.

Comment: So, it seems a bug from them. Possibly they store too much data in stack (which it is not supposed for large memory, for that we have the heap). (or possibly they documented that max size of images, because many OCR work better with small images).

Comment: Well, let's say that everything works fine on one PC, but on a weaker PC such troubles, I checked when scanning consumes about 1GB of RAM.

Comment: Working fine on one PC doesn't make correct the code. As you see, the code doesn't work on some computers, so now you know the reason: bad code that uses too much stack. Not all computers can provide so much stacks (stack may be around 1 MB size). So either update the computers or file a bug report, so that code works on most computers. The problem is not in your program.